# json/php: how to get information from nested and non-nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I am working with RIOT API (league of legends) and I have this webhost where I test my code: [20ff.net](http://20ff.net). I am using this code, the output is shown on the website.

```
ini_set("display_errors", "1"); error_reporting(E_ALL);

$ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/challenger?type=RANKED_SOLO_5x5&api_key=***');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($response, true);

    foreach($json['entries'] as $entry){

        echo $entry['playerOrTeamName'] . ' - Division: ' . $entry['division'] . ' - ' . $entry['leaguePoints'] . ' LP' . "<br/>";
        }
```

These are all nested arrays, but theres 1 array that contains information thats outside the `entries` array, it is called `name`. Name contains the name of the division the player is in, eg: Challenger, diamond, platinum, gold, silver or bronze. I want to use this in front of the `$entry['division']` so the output will be `Division: Diamond 1` (for example) and not `Division: 1`. This is the reference guide: https://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods#!/828/2921

How do i fix this, i failed to try with two foreach commands.

Edit json response:

```
{
"name":"Miss Fortune's Weaponmasters",
"tier":"CHALLENGER",
"queue":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
"entries": [{
    "playerOrTeamId":"43211669",
    "playerOrTeamName":"Zednic",
    "division":"I",
    "league‌​Points":708,
    "wins":394,
    "isHotStreak":false,
    "isVeteran":false,
    "isFreshBlood":false‌​,
    "isInactive":false
}]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the json, eg the contents of `$response`

Comment: i have included all code. this is what you wanted to see or did u want to see `var_dump($response)` ?

Comment: Well i need to see the raw json data. Simply visit the api url in your browser and copy paste the json into yout question. I cant do it myself because i dont have an api key

Comment: `{"name":"Miss Fortune's Weaponmasters","tier":"CHALLENGER","queue":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5","entries":` <-- thats the first layer array, and this is 2nd layer --> `{"playerOrTeamId":"43211669","playerOrTeamName":"Zednic","division":"I","leaguePoints":708,"wins":394,"isHotStreak":false,"isVeteran":false,"isFreshBlood":false,"isInactive":false}`. It seems I was looking for wrong information. Its `tier` i was looking for, cuz that one holds the names: challenger, diamond, platinum, gold, silver and bronze. And `name` holds the name of the division tier it seems. Could I use `name` too?

Comment: I dont know how to include `tier` and `name` while in 2nd layer array.

Comment: You can access any of the top level elements directly whilst withing the loop, please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming i got the correct json structure from your comments:

```
$json = json_decode($response, true);
foreach($json['entries'] as $entry){
    echo $entry['playerOrTeamName'] . ' - Division: ' . $json['tier'] . ' ' . $entry['division'] . ' - ' . $entry['leaguePoints'] . ' LP' . "<br/>";
}
```

The point is you can access the original array from inside the loop, eg `$json['tier']` not just the current loop item

Comment: works! thank you sir. I understand how it works now!

Comment: @floppy Great, glad i could help. And just a tip, in future if someone asks you to add code to your question, press the edit button and put it into the actual question, rather than in a comment, as its much easier to read